# How to groupby timeseries and aggregate start/stop times in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```html
       data  start  stop
    10    1.0   1.5
    10    2.0   2.5
    10    3.0   3.5
    10    4.0   4.5
    10    5.0   5.5
    10    6.0   6.5
    10    7.0   7.5
    10    8.0   8.5
    14    9.0   9.5
    14   10.0  10.5
    10   11.0  11.5
    10   12.0  12.5
    10   13.0  13.5
    10   14.0  14.5
    14   15.0  15.5
    10   16.0  16.5
    10   17.0  17.5
    11   18.0  18.5
    11   19.0  19.5
    11   20.0  20.5
```

I want to group the df by df.data and aggregate the df.start and df.stop time for the group in columns. It should look like this:

```html
    data  start  stop
    10    1.0   8.5
    14    9.0   10.5
    10   11.0   14.5
    14   15.0   15.5
    10   16.0   17.5
    11   18.0   20.5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `ne` + `shift` + `cumsum` to group by consecutive values. Then choose the proper aggregation for each column. Given the ordering of your data you could equally use `'first'` and `'last'` to aggregate start and stop respectively.

```
d = {'data': 'first', 'start': 'min', 'stop': 'max'}   # How to aggregate
s = df.data.ne(df.data.shift(1)).cumsum().rename(None) # How to group

df.groupby(s).agg(d)
#   data  start  stop
#1    10    1.0   8.5
#2    14    9.0  10.5
#3    10   11.0  14.5
#4    14   15.0  15.5
#5    10   16.0  17.5
#6    11   18.0  20.5
```

Comment: looks like one can use `'start':'first', 'stop':'last'` as well, save some comparison :-)

Comment: df.groupby((df.data!=df.data.shift()).cumsum()).agg({'data':'first', 'start':'first', 'stop':'last'}).set_index('data')  works as well